# Highlight td if its value is one

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this.

```
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and jquery code to highlight the `td` if its value is `one`

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td:contains('one')").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

And code will make the td highligted if its value is `one two` also. I want to highlight only the td which have `one`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is not a good fit for this as it just checks whether the given string is present anywhere in the element, use a manual [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do it

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'one'
}).css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

See demo at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yjbp/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $("tr td:contains('one')").each(function(){
      $(this).css("background","#6a5acd");
 });
```

see demo at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yjbp/1/)

Comment: It's the same. `:contains` will select `one two` too. Because it contains `one`

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` function is really not a good fit for this usage.  I would recommand `filter` instead.

Here is the syntax: of what you will want to do.

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "one"
}).css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

And here is a jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xDP9d/